# How to restore deleted files from flash drive?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, file-recovery

In last time I am discovered than some files are deleting from flash drive. Don't khow why.
How to restore deleted files from flash drive?
OS - Ubuntu or OpenSolaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if you have a .trash-[yourusername] at the root of the flash drive.

```
cd /path/to/flash
ls -la|grep trash
```